# What is wrong with my syntax in this simple procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Im an SQL Server guy and struggling with PLSQL. I think it is the way I am using the p_rc cursor

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_EMAILLINKSCRUD" (
    pAction IN nvarchar2,
    pStormId IN number,
    p_rc OUT Pkg_Types.grc
)
AS
BEGIN
    if pAction = 'getManagerEmails' then
        OPEN p_rc FOR
        select * from table1;

    else if pAction = 'getSentEmailLinks' then
        OPEN p_rc FOR
        select * 
        from table2 
        where stormId = pStormId; 
    end if;

END SP_EMAILLINKSCRUD;
```

Comment: What's not working? How do you execute it? also do you want `"` in its name? also are you using Oracle?

Comment: it wouldn't compile but William solved it

Comment: It's worth finding out how to list the compilation errors in whatever tool you are using. Also I agree with @user7294900, doublequoting identifiers should rarely be needed and is just asking for trouble. (Also personally I never use uppercase for programming but it's up to you.)

Answer (score 4):

You started a new nested `if` here but didn't close it:

```
else if pAction = 'getSentEmailLinks' then
```

That should probably be:

```
elsif pAction = 'getSentEmailLinks' then
```

Comment: dear god, i tried that early on but spelled it elseif not elsif. Oracle...what can ya do!  Anyway thanks William

Comment: @Roto: don't blame Oracle. PL/SQL is basically "Ada with embedded SQL", and in Ada an `IF` statement is `IF...{ELSIF...}[ELSE...]END IF`. So, blame the government. :-)

Comment: Shellscript and Perl use `elif`. I think it’s only PHP that has `elseif`. The syntax is what it is...

Comment: More seriously perhaps, the languages where you use `else if` a lot (and typically written on one line) are ones with brackets instead of `then` and no `end`, so they don’t need an `elsif` keyword.